# PowerShell | Add DIR to PATH | Use in Script

Tags: powershell

I've been learning PowerShell and the best way to learn is by doing.
Scenario:

```
D:\Tools\chainsaw\chainsaw.exe
D:\Tools\chainsaw\mapping_files\
D:\Tools\chainsaw\sigma_rules\
```

I added `D:\Tools\chainsaw\` to my PATH

I have my Event Logs in let's say `C:\TestEventLogs\` which I make my current Directory in PowerShell

```
chainsaw.exe hunt ./ --rules sigma_rules/ --mapping mapping_files/sigma-mapping.yml --csv text.csv
```

Now a command like the below would fail because although PowerShell can find chainsaw.exe because it's in my PATH, it's unable to locate the other folders specified by the other two arguments `--rules sigma_rules/ --mapping mapping_files/sigma-mapping.yml`

Any tips or workaround to this would be appreciated. I am trying to automate some stuff using PS functions and arguments, and I'm stuck at making this work because I don't want to hardcode `D:\Tools\chainsaw\mapping_files\` and `D:\Tools\chainsaw\sigma_rules\` in the commandline.

Comment: Perhaps adding the path `D:\Tools\chainsaw` to the Environment is what you're looking for? Then you can address this with something like `$env:Chainsaw\mapping_files\sigma-mapping.yml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented, it may be of use for you to create an Environment variable for the file path:

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("CHAINSAW", D:\Tools\chainsaw, "Machine")
```

Then you can use that as `$env:CHAINSAW\mapping_files\sigma-mapping.yml`

Comment: Thank you both of you! After posting the question I managed to add an ENV to achieve this. I'm relieved that two kind and helpful strangers on the Internet also thought of the same method - thank you once again.